# Does network monitoring tools help in detecting spywares?

Tags: windows-7, spyware, network-monitoring

Is it possible for spywares/ virus not to be detected by network monitoring tool ( for eg [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb897437)) if they are sending information/files over internet ?

Comment: Yes, why are you asking? Are you doing something or just a general question?

Comment: I am asking because I know anti-spywares may not be effective. But how come traffic monitoring softwares cannot catch that some app is sending data over internet ?

Comment: Because malware can interfere with the traffic monitoring software. If a PC has ANY malware on it, you can't trust ANYTHING on that computer: you don't know how much access the malware got. Monitoring stuff can help, but you really need a separate computer to monitor and report on issues for security stuff; you can't rely on the primary.

Comment: @cpast can these malwares transmit files/ documents etc without being detected ?

Comment: I believe it can send stuff without being detected by software on the compromised machine (if it gains admin access, it can do _anything_: the general guideline is that once a system is compromised and a malicious user gains admin access, you no longer control that computer, can't recover, and need to start over). Now, you *can* monitor the network traffic, just not using tools on the compromised machine.

Comment: That said: Why do you think it's infected?

Comment: I am not sure if it is. What is the way to detect if it is infected ? I have shared my laptop with others, any malware can come knowingly/unknowingly from them.

Comment: @cpast do u think ubuntu is safe from malware/spyware ?

Comment: Not necessarily. While *nix systems normally are _safer_ from malware (due, in part, to them encouraging you towards a more secure setup), no computer is totally safe. The best way to ensure security would be another computer, one which is incredibly locked down. The more stuff that gets done on the computer, the bigger a risk it is.

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to where you are running the network monitoring and how low level the malware is.

Most malware that you see (from my experience) is not low-level enough to re-write networking stacks to where local monitoring tools would not see the traffic. This could happen though, so there is always a change of the traffic blindly passing through. You are getting more into root-kits and things like that, not you everyday malware when this happens.

If you run the network monitoring on the gateway/router, you are going to see the traffic from the machine, now matter how low-level the malware is. This will show you all traffic coming from a host if it is on the gateway, no matter how the traffic is disguised.

Comment: I donot have control on the router it is provided by my organisation. Could you suggest best way to figure out if there is a malware or not ?